# Find all spinners views without using findViewById() in android

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I have more than 100 spinners in my xml. Is there any way to find all spinners without using findViewById() to all the 100 spinners? It's tedious and I don't mean by some creation tools or something like that, I mean if there is a code to solve this problem. I need to connect each spinner to a string-array from my array.xml file.

Comment: 100 spinners?  are you sure your strategy is right?

Comment: its look like you want find person without his name...

Comment: Are you sure that's not supposed to be an expendable list with dialogs or something? I mean, 100 spinners HAS to be overkill.

Comment: table?  what table do you mean?

Comment: There are some categories and each category has sub categories, each of which has the option to choose from spinners why it is so much spinners. Actually there are many tables.

Comment: I mean string-array with items

Comment: use an ExpandableListView for such structure

Comment: I don't know how ExpandableList helping me. I will describe you how it's look like. I have some categories, for each categories i have sub caregories and each sub category i have 3 spinners it's, look like table with 4 columns and rows as number of sub categories.

Answer (score 2):

```
Spinner spinner;
LinearLayout layout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
for (int i =0 ;i <layout.getChildCount(); i++){
    if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Spinner){
            spinner = (Spinner) layout.getChildAt(i);
    }
}
```

Where LinearLayout is yours main layout which contains spinners. You can add spinner to list or do with it whatever you want.

Comment: so you probably mean layout = findViewById or something but not new LinearLayout...

Comment: and honestly, while your answer is perfectly ok you really shouldn't have answerd that question to discourage OP from that bad practices (100+ spinners...)

Answer (score 0):

If your spinners aren't in the same ViewGroup, you'll have to do a full transversal like this:

```
public static List<Spinner> getAllSpinnersIn(ViewGroup view) {
    List<Spinner> list = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
    getAllSpinnersIn(view, list);
    return list;
}

private static void getAllSpinnersIn(ViewGroup view, List<Spinner> outList) {
    for (int i = 0, len = view.getChildCount(); i < len; i++) {
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            getAllSpinnersIn((ViewGroup) child, outList);
        } else if (child instanceof Spinner) {
            outList.add((Spinner) child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This had troubled me as well. I adopted sergio91pt's method but found 0 spinners every time. Later I discovered the problem is that Spinner is an indirect subclass of ViewGroup. So when we do

> if (child instanceof ViewGroup)

better to do one more check inside the if branch

> if (!(child instanceof Spinner))

so the code will be

```
private static void getAllSpinnersIn(ViewGroup view, List<Spinner> outList) {
    for (int i = 0, len = view.getChildCount(); i < len; i++) {
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            if (!(child instanceof Spinner))
                getAllSpinnersIn((ViewGroup) child, outList);
        } else if (child instanceof Spinner) {
            outList.add((Spinner) child);
        }
    }
}
```